# What is a trapdoor permutation?

Tags: rsa, public-key, terminology, trapdoor

Can anyone explain to me what a trapdoor one-way permutation is?  Is RSA a trapdoor one-way permutation?

---

Context: I was reading about [ring signatures](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RST01.pdf).  On page 560, it describes steps to implementing a ring signature. I am confused by step 3, where $g()$ is a trap-door permutation.  The paper briefly says that $g()$ is an RSA trap-door permutation. I thought that RSA was a public-key encryption protocol.  Is RSA a trapdoor permutation?

Comment: I edited your question to get to the essence of it, about what a trapdoor permutation is.  If you still have questions after learning about trapdoor one-way permutations, please post a separate question with the question about ring signatures.

Comment: The name RSA is used for multiple things: A specific trapdoor one-way permutation, several public-key encryption schemes build on this permutation, several public key signature schemes build on this permutation, and a company which markets these algorithms (and other security-related stuff). Also, the initials of the inventors (Rivest, Shamir, Adleman)..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read Wikipedia: [Trapdoor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function)

Then read [Luca Trevisan's lecture notes](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/cs276-lecture-19-trapdoor-permutations/) (jump straight to section 2. Trapdoor Permutations and Encryption).  Or, read any other textbook or lecture notes that covers trapdoor permutations.

For instance, if $(n,e)$ is a RSA public key, then $f(x) = x^e \bmod n$ is a trapdoor permutation.  It is a permutation, since the function $f:S\to S$ is bijective (where $S=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$).  It is a trapdoor one-way permutation, since given $x$ and the public key, we can easily compute $f(x)$, but given $y$ and the public key, it is difficult to compute $f^{-1}(y)$; yet with the private key (the trapdoor), we can easily compute $f^{-1}(y)$, given $y$.

That should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I get the general idea, but I don't quite understand the math behind it. They describe the function _g(x)_, which uses the RSA's public exponent _e_ and modulus _n_. What would _g(x)^-1_ be in this case when provided with my RSA's private component _d_?

Comment: @user1812844,  If $g(x)=x^e \bmod n$, then $g^{-1}(y) = y^d \bmod n$.  Again, read lecture notes or other stuff on trapdoor one-way permutations and RSA -- this is standard stuff that should be covered in textbooks.